# What do the vscode 'cube' and 'spanner' debugger symbols mean

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

[image]

What do the vscode 'cube' and 'spanner' debugger symbols mean. Please see inserted picture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**cube** means a method (or a function)

**spanner** means a property that is not a function

Comment: Thank you , any idea idea why these symbols are used - I don't see the connection to their meanings.

Comment: @user1592380 _Visual Studio_ uses very similar/identical symbols.  VS Code was probably inspired by Visual Studio to use them because many would be familiar with them already.